# Why is this while loop an infinite loop?

Tags: c#

I want to execute the contents of a loop a maximum of 3 times and every time the program executes, I want it to generate a different number. So the first run could be 2, then 3, then 1, then 2, etc...

Here is the code I have written:

```
       int i = new Random().Next(3);
        while (i <= 3)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

            i--;
        }**
```

However, this ends up in an infinite loop. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

THANKS!

Comment: It's not an "infinite" loop .. but it will loop for a *very long time* (say, about 2 billion iterations until an underflow, which takes noticeable time because of writing the the Console). The initial values of `i` are 0,1,2 so the Random is a *useless* unrelated detail. Consider: `int i = 2 /* max of Random.Next(3) */; while (i <= 3) { ..; i-- }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are always decrementing the variable, so it will always be less than 3

Comment: Actually, you'll finally reach `int.MinValue` and after another `i--` you'll get `int.MaxValue`. But I'm pretty sure that's not what OP is looking for :)

Comment: Infinite for very small values of infinity.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek So c# actually "loops" around once the minimum value has been hit and goes to the max?

Comment: @ylun Yes, that's called overflowing. You can read about it at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Thank you, I had not known about this before. It's incredibly interesting

Answer (score 1):

i will always be less than 3... until it hits Int.MinValue - 1 (overflow).

Answer (score 1):

Your correct way of doing it should be setting a minimum value as well as a maximum value such as below

```
int i = new Random().Next(3);

while (i>0 && i <= 3)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        i--;
    }**
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you change the code to say 'i++' instead of 'i--' you'll get the result you were looking for.

```
int i = new Random().Next(3);
        while (i <= 3)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

            i++;
        }**
```